# What is the best way to use InstallShield together with Subversion?

Tags: svn, installshield

Does someone know a good Subversion client plug-in for InstallShield?

Suppose I use TortoiseSVN client on our setups-preparing PC. 
I’m interested to know where and how to control multiple project builds.

InstallShield project, script directory files and/or corresponding Data directory tree with files changes build by build.
Data directory tree for our projects content from 100 to 1.1 GB of binary and text files.

I see the following options:

- InstallShield project file, script directory together with corresponding
        Data directory tree save in Subversion repository;
- InstallShield project file and script directory save in Subversion repository.
       Data directory tree versions save on file server because of large data size;
- Don’t use source control for setup projects.

Comment: Are you trying to use Subversion from within InstallShield as part of a software distribution scheme (installer calls tortoiseSVn which pulls from a repository)? Or pull resources from Subversion into a project where you build an InstallShield package?

Answer (score 4):

I use CVS with our InstallShield setup, but I don't have anywhere near as much data as you do.

- I keep the .ism and Setup.rul file in CVS, alongside all the product source code.
- The entire tree is checked out and copied over the network to the build server.
- The compile is performed, and then the binary files and installer data files are copied into a separate directory
- [The command-line InstallShield tool is invoked](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/UsingIScmdBld.htm), and the setup is generated.
- The build results are copied back onto the network share for packaging.

One thing I suggest is making sure that you are using the [XML-based .ism file format](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/ExportProj2Text.htm).  It's a bit larger on disk, but it works much better with a source code management system.  It also lets you manually make changes to the file, as well as seeing exactly what changed between versions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think the way you use InstallShield with source control (CVS) correct. Our projects specific are many mutable binary files that I cannot automatic generate/build as executables file types from his sources.